# Why vim plugins have a check on &cp

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system

I'm trying to wrap my head around vim plugin development and I see a constant check on a variable to see if the plugin has already been loaded like:

```
if exists('g:loaded_plugin') || &cp
  finish
endif
```

This makes sense since it's trying to not load the plugin twice but why is it checking the second part?

I've searched on the documentation on the `&` and the `cp` command and it's not ringing anything on my head. As said in the documentation, the `&` is used to replay the last substitution command and the `cp` is to get to the next Error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That checks for the `compatible` option being set. Usually you don't want plugins to be run when the compatible option is set, because well for one Vim wouldn't actually be compatible anymore and seconds of all, the compatible option e.g. does not allow for line continuations e.g.

```
let a = 'foobar'
     \ . ' and more text'
```

You could fix that, by setting a specific `cpotions` flag, but the general consensus in the Vim community seems to be, to just not bother and skip loading the plugin if Vim starts in compatible mode.

See [`:help :let-option`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-option)

Answer (score 2):

To just add a bit more to this, take a look at `:help expression-syntax` specifically `expr9` which shows you can use `&option` to evaluate the option to its numerical value.

In Vimscript, 0 is false and non-zero is true. With that said, `cp` is an abbreviation of `compatible` and that means the `if` condition is checking the numeric value of the boolean `compatible` option.